# How to use UseEffect cleaning on async function for Firebase Login?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, use-effect

I have not been able to use the useEffect function to not get the following warning:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates >a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a >useEffect cleanup function.

here's my code

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Card, Button, Form, Alert } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useAuth } from '../context/AuthContext';
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Login() {

    const emailRef = useRef();
    const passwordRef = useRef();
    const { login } = useAuth();
    const [error, setError] = useState('');
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const history = useHistory();



    async function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            setError('')
            setLoading(true)
            await login(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value)
            history.push('/')
        } catch {
            setError('Failed to Log In')
        }
        setLoading(false)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Card>
                <Card.Body>
                    <h2 className='text-center mb-4'>
                        Log In
                </h2>
                    {error && <Alert variant='danger'>{error}</Alert>}
                    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <Form.Group id='email'>
                            <Form.Label>
                                Email
                        </Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type='email' ref={emailRef} required />
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Form.Group id='password'>
                            <Form.Label>
                                Password
                        </Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type='password' ref={passwordRef} required />
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Button disabled={loading} className='w-100' type='submit'>
                            Log In
                    </Button>
                    </Form>
                    <div className='w-100 text-center mt-3'>
                        <Link to='/forgot-password'>Forgot Password?</Link>
                    </div>
                </Card.Body>

            </Card>

            <div className='w-100 text-center mt-2'>
                Need an account? <Link to='/signup'>Sign Up</Link>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

I have tried several things including:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Card, Button, Form, Alert } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useAuth } from '../context/AuthContext';
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Login() {

    const emailRef = useRef();
    const passwordRef = useRef();
    const { login } = useAuth();
    const [error, setError] = useState('');
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const history = useHistory();


    useEffect(() => {

    async function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            setError('')
            setLoading(true)
            await login(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value)
            history.push('/')
        } catch {
            setError('Failed to Log In')
        }
        setLoading(false)
    }

    handleSubmit();

    return handleSubmit;

    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <Card>
                <Card.Body>
                    <h2 className='text-center mb-4'>
                        Log In
                </h2>
                    {error && <Alert variant='danger'>{error}</Alert>}
                    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <Form.Group id='email'>
                            <Form.Label>
                                Email
                        </Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type='email' ref={emailRef} required />
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Form.Group id='password'>
                            <Form.Label>
                                Password
                        </Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type='password' ref={passwordRef} required />
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Button disabled={loading} className='w-100' type='submit'>
                            Log In
                    </Button>
                    </Form>
                    <div className='w-100 text-center mt-3'>
                        <Link to='/forgot-password'>Forgot Password?</Link>
                    </div>
                </Card.Body>

            </Card>

            <div className='w-100 text-center mt-2'>
                Need an account? <Link to='/signup'>Sign Up</Link>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

Chrome also shows me a warning a bout a password leak every time I Login or Log out I´m not sure if it is because of this problem.

[image: Check your passwords]

Please help

Comment: Don't worry about the password leak warning, it's just because chrome think's your site is supporting phishing.

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `useEffect` ( create one more ) should look like this :

```
let mounted = true;

useEffect(()=>{
    return function cleanup(){
        mounted = false
    }
})
```

Now check for the mounted value while updating a state, especially the `loading` one